# Insert new row iwth value in first column error

Tags: excel, vba, row

Yesterday I added a post. I cannot seem to update, so pasting the newest error in this new post:
The intent is this. In the active cell, when I press a button I will record the max value and increment it by one from a table (So if the table said 8, I will insert a 9). I will then add a new row to the table, and in that row, in the respective column (ShotNo) I will insert the value (9).
I am getting an error in this line in the With statement. Method Range of Object Range failed.

```
.Range(1) = WorksheetFunction.Max(table.ListColumns("ShotNo").Range) + 1
```

---

```
Sub RecordShot()

    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Range
    Dim value As Integer

    Set table = Worksheets("GameSheetH").ListObjects("SOGP1")
  'First add the next shot to the Active Cell
  ActiveCell.value = WorksheetFunction.Max(table.ListColumns("ShotNo").Range) + 1

    'Add the same value in the SOGP1 table .
    'Here is the first step in editing the SOGP1 table. Check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    
    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
        If Application.CountBlank(lastRow) < lastRow.Columns.Count Then
            table.ListRows.Add
        End If
    End If
    'Iterate through the last row and populate it with the next value in the row ShotNo
    If table.ListRows.Count = 0 Then 'If table is totally empty, set lastRow as first entry
        table.ListRows.Add Position:=1
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(1).Range
    Else
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
    End If
    
    With lastRow
        .Range(1) = WorksheetFunction.Max(table.ListColumns("ShotNo").Range) + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

I am trying to harvest hints online to create this code ... I am not very adept at VBA but tasked with this effort. So many thanks for any assistance

Comment: `.range(1)` isn't a valid range, I'm not sure what you are trying to refer to with that. The first column in the row?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `lastRow` is a Range object.  `.Range` is a property not Method of a Range object.  Change `.Range(1)` to `.Value`

Comment: `.range` is a property of a range object.

Comment: I missed it when looking at the object explorer.  Thank you @Warcupine.

Comment: Fantastic That worked! thanks a ton - except it inserts the value into every column. I only want it to insert the value in the first column. Any ideas

Comment: can you recommend the solution? CHanging to value added the value to every column in the last row, and i only need to insert into the first column of the last row. thanks

Comment: @kmo `.columns(1).value` or `.cells(1, 1).value` or `.range("A1").value` though that is not a good way as it isn't referring to A1 as it appears on the sheet.

Comment: thanks. now it works as desired. Appreciate it